# Firebase not usable in iOS app extensions since 3.8.0 due to GTMSessionFetcher sharedApplication #AskFirebase

Tags: ios, firebase, share-extension, gtmsessionfetcher

I'm using Firebase in my latest app. After upgrading the pods to 3.10.0 the share extension of the app can't be built. The Firebase pods depend on `GTMSessionFetcher` which uses `sharedApplication` which is not available in app extensions.

I'm using the following pods in my extension:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 3.7.0'
pod 'Firebase/Crash', '~> 3.7.0'
pod 'Firebase/Auth', '~> 3.7.0'
pod 'Firebase/Database', '~> 3.7.0'
```

I rolled back to version 3.7.0. This is the last version not relying on `sharedApplication`.

Will this be fixed in an upcoming version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in upcoming GTMSessionFetcher and Firebase versions.

In the meantime, since recent Firebase versions reference GTMSessionFetcher as a source pod, the offending code can be ifdef'ed or commented out for code running in app extensions:

[image]

Comment: I read about this approach but were unsure. Thanks for clarification. Works!